# Why is this Python ascii string not equivalent to a regular string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison, ascii

Why does the following fail?

```
assert ascii("cat") == "cat" => False
```

(I suppose it has something to do with Python's comparison for strings / the encoding of the strings once the ASCII function has finished.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the output of `ascii` is something like this:

```
>>> ascii('cat')
"'cat'"
```

which is clearly different from just `'cat'`.

`ascii` returns the `repr` version of the string object, which can be used with `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` to regenerate the string object.

```
>>> eval (ascii('cat'))
'cat'
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(ascii('cat'))
'cat'
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting):

> The `str()` function is meant to return representations of values which
>   are fairly human-readable, while `repr()` is meant to generate
>   representations which can be read by the interpreter (or will force a
>   `SyntaxError` if there is no equivalent syntax). For objects which don’t
>   have a particular representation for human consumption, `str()` will
>   return the same value as `repr()`. Many values, such as numbers or
>   structures like lists and dictionaries, have the same representation
>   using either function. **Strings** and floating point numbers, in
>   particular, have **two distinct** representations.